# Validate JSON String

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to make a JSON String but I am always getting an exception while validating the JSON String using any tool -

Below is my JSON String which I am not able to validate properly -

> {"script":"#!/bin/bash hello=$jj1 echo $hello echo $jj1 echo $jj2 for
>   el1 in $jj3 do echo \"$el1\" done for el2 in $jj4 do echo \"$el2\"
>   done for i in $( ls ); do echo item: $i done"}

It is always giving me -

```
Invalid characters found.
```

What else I am supposed to escape?

Below is my shell script which I want to represent as JSON String -

```
#!/bin/bash

hello=$jj1

echo $hello

echo $jj1
echo $jj2

for el1 in $jj3
do
    echo "$el1"
done

for el2 in $jj4
do
    echo "$el2"
done

for i in $( ls ); do
    echo item: $i
done
```

How do I use jackson or other libraries to make the above a valid JSON String.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: That is another issue. I am not sure how to use jackson or other libraries to make this shell script as a valid JSON document.. So I decided to represent this shell script as a JSON String manually.. Updated the details in the question.

Comment: Ok then I misunderstood `getting an exception while validating the JSON String using any tool`. Which tool did you use?

Comment: I used [JSON Formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter)

Comment: Aahh.. Might be they have different window in that tool.. Earlier, it was showing not valid.. And I guess, I made some changes then again I tried validating it, so I guess somehow it showed me the previous window. Anyways.. Thanks for confirming that.. Apart from that, is there any possibility of generating a valid JSON String in Java if I have a shell script like that?

Comment: i checked your json that is valid.

Comment: The JSON is valid, according to the online parser at http://json.parser.online.fr/ .

Comment: @HotLicks: it is *not* valid. There is a literal newline inside json string (between quotes). You might have removed the newline on copy-paste. Or OP doesn't use `<pre>` or other format preserving tags.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - It is not possible to tell if there is a literal newline in the original source, since it is "quoted" rather than presented as "code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [.mayBeJSON(String str)](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/util/JSONUtils.html#mayBeJSON%28java.lang.String%29) available in the [JSONUtils](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/util/JSONUtils.html) library for validating JSON in java

or else

A wild idea for validating JSON, try parsing it and catch the exception:

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String test)
{
    boolean valid = false;
    try {
        new JSONObject(test);
        valid = true;
    }
    catch(JSONException ex) { 
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is indeed a valid JSON raw string. In shell terminal, you do need to use single quotes to quote it in order to satisfy command prompt escape sequence.

```
{"script":"#!/bin/bash hello=$jj1 echo $hello echo $jj1 echo $jj2 for el1 in $jj3 do echo \"$el1\" done for el2 in $jj4 do echo \"$el2\" done for i in $( ls ); do echo item: $i done"}
```

Like this:

> $ echo '{"script":"#!/bin/bash hello=$jj1 echo $hello echo $jj1 echo $jj2 for el1 in $jj3 do echo \"$el1\" done for el2 in $jj4 do echo \"$el2\" done for i in $( ls ); do echo item: $i done"}' | jq '.'